# I am a very novice Java programmer, this program won't print the inputs that I want it to and I don't know why

Tags: java

This should print the inputs but it doesn't, it definitely reads them because an exception is thrown if you do the wrong datatype, but it is either not printing correctly or not changing the variables or possibly both, could someone please explain why, it would be much appreciated. thanks for at least reading this dumb question :)

```
package Stg1;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0;
        String fName = null;
        String sName = null;

        storeContact();
        System.out.println(cntc1.fName + " " + cntc1.sName + " " + cntc1.num);
    }
    public static class Contact {
        String fName;
        String sName;
        int num;
    }
    public static Contact cntc1 = new Contact();

    public static void storeContact() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        Contact cntc1 = new Contact();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the person:");
        cntc1.fName = scnr.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the surname of the person:");
        cntc1.sName = scnr.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the number:");
        cntc1.num = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("A record created!");
        System.out.println("A Phone Book with a single record created!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The static **field** `cntc1` is different from the **local variable** `cntc1` in the `storeContact` method. Remove line 2 from the method, since: *A)* you don't want a local variable, and *B)* the field is already initialized with an object.

Comment: It requires a lot of modifications. Kindly first go through classes and objects then basic OOP concepts. It will help you a lot to understand how to write program in Java using OOP concepts. Later you can try editing your program.

Comment: The variable `cntct1` inside `main` function points to the static global variable which is empty. The variable `cntct1` inside `storeContact` points to the local variable which is destroyed as soon as the program exits that function.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined cntc1 twice, one act as a static and other inside `storeContact`

```
public static Contact cntc1 = new Contact();

    public static void storeContact() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        Contact cntc1 = new Contact();
```

Remove `Contact cntc1 = new Contact();` code it will work.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues.

- You have initialized two Contact objects, one static and another inside the store contact function as a local variable. Currently, you are assigning local variable and using static Contact object which is the problem
- It is better to remove the static contact object as it wont allow you to work with multiple contact objects simultaneously. So better return the Contact object while calling the store contact function.

The following code should work:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Contact {
    String fName;
    String sName;
    int num;
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Contact cntc1 = storeContact();
        System.out.println(cntc1.fName + " " + cntc1.sName + " " + cntc1.num);
    }

    public static Contact storeContact() {
        Contact cntc1 = new Contact();
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the person:");
        cntc1.fName = scnr.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the surname of the person:");
        cntc1.sName = scnr.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the number:");
        cntc1.num = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("A record created!");
        System.out.println("A Phone Book with a single record created!");
        return cntc1;
    }
}
```

For having another Contact object from user, you can use `Contact cntct2 = storeContact()` which was not possible with before code, as it will overwrite previous contents.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot, I just have 2 questions to clarify, in this line: "Contact cntc1 = storeContact" does that just mean do that method with this instance of this class? and also if the storeContact method is not void, shouldn't that cause a compilation error, since it does not have any return statements?

Comment: I missed adding the return statement @Poobean. Updated answer.

Comment: oh okay thank you so much, this has helped quite a bit, I don't know why I didn't see there were 2 instances of cntc1, I plan to expand on this code and make it better, thank you I have learned a few new statements as well that I was not taught in the course I am doing. :)